# Depth First Search

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, depth-first-search

Perform Depth-first Search on the graph shown starting with vertex a. When you traverse the neighbours, process them in alphabetical order.

The question is to find the DFI, Level and the Parent of each vertex.

Here is a picture of it:

[image]

I'm unsure of how to get going with this, it is a practice question for an upcoming exam. I know for depth first search, it uses a stack and it will start at vertex a and go in alphabetical order in the stack but i'm not sure how I would get the values for each of the columns. Can someone explain further or help me with this?

Comment: Are you asking about how to write code to compute the values or are you asking what the values in the columns should be for the given graph? (In other words, do you know how to compute the answer by hand?)

Answer (score 2):

So you start at 'a' and must traverse the nodes in alphabetical order so from a you either have the option of going to b or g so you choose b because it is first alphabetically. from b your only choice is g and so on....

now for your values. the parent of a is null since you have no previous nodes the parent of b is a and the parent of g is b and so on.

the dfs level is the level that it would end up on a tree. so imagine that you do your traversal then erase all lines that weren't part of the traversal. and then you take your root and 'shake it out' what i mean is you rearrange it so that it looks like a tree. (this particular graph is very uninteresting) and then you assign levels based on that tree.

And the dfs index is simply the order in which you touched the nodes.

The folowing are for your graph but using g as a starting point....I think it makes it slightly more intersting

[image]
the numbers are the order in which the edges were taken.

[image: Example of dfs starting at node g]

Here is what i was talking about when i said 'shake it out' this is what your tree looks like and in blue i show the level of each node(0 based). I hope the images make it a little more understandable.

[image]

the one i drew( the terrible free hand one) was formed by deleting all of the edges that weren't used and then rearranging them to look like a tree.

You can think of the depth as how many steps did i have to take from the root to get to the current node. so from g to b is 1 step so depth of 1 from g to i 3 because we go from g->c->d->i 3 steps. after you have made your traversal you ignore the fact that you can in fact get from g to i in two steps(g->h->i) because it wasnt part of the traversal

Comment: The second picture doesn't really make too much sense ... like is the 1 referring to C or A? and in your case you made the root G which is 0 in the DSF Level. Can you further explain with the case of mine? Because I don't know what the next level for like B would be. A is a given, but how would I get the level for B,c,D, etc.? Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: the 1 is referring to both C and a, and they are at the same level and have the same parent. b and d are at the same level but b has a as its parent and d has c as its parent.

Comment: the reason i chose g as the root is because it yields a traversal with slightly more complexity and illustrates the point of multiple nodes being able to be at the same level and have the same parent.

Comment: How did you form a graph like that for the DSF Level? Is there a specific way of something you did? I would also like to attempt that for my example. Hope you can respond back again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The index is simply the number in order that the node is visited. `a` is first, write `1` there. Knowing depth first search as you do, you should know what the second node is; so write `2` under that. Depth is how high a node is; every time you deepen the depth, it increases, and whenever you go shallower, it's less. So `a` is on depth 1; the next node and its sister will be on depth `2`, etc. The parent is the letter identifying the node that you just came from; so `a` has no parent, and the node with index `2` will have `a` as parent.

If your class uses a zero-based numbering system, replace `2` in the above paragraph with `1`, and `1` with `0`. If you have no idea what "zero-based numbering system" is, ignore this paragraph.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your response. So for the Index for G, would it have 3 in it? I know a is the first one as that is given, and 2 would be B for the index, but it's difficult when you get to like H. Can you clarify that please?

Comment: @user2958631 h will be last and you are correct about g it will be index 3.

Comment: A = index 1, B = index 2, G= index 3, C = index 4? Like what's confusing me the most for the index, is how come the letter H is skipped and how do you know what index will be next? I thought it was supposed to be in alphabetical ordering.

Comment: @user2958631 to get to g froma we first go a->b->g. we from g we can either go to h or c we pick c because it is first alphabetically and then from c we can look at h i or d we pick d because it comes first alphabetically. and so on h doesn't get skipped persay the other letters get chosed first. (well i guess that is a form of skipping)

Comment: Alphabetical ordering between *siblings*; so `c` and its subtree comes before `h` and its subtree. `h` is not skipped, it's just later.

Comment: @thermite , Okay, so for the indices I just said: A = index 1, B = index 2, G= index 3, C = index 4, D=5, I=6 etc  is that correct so far? I took into consideration the alphabetical ordering you said that needed to be done for the DFS INDEX.

Comment: Alphabetical ordering on siblings is not needed for DFS, it is required by your instructor so everyone has same results. The only requirement in DFS is "pick a node you haven't picked before". And yes, your order is correct, given the task description.

Comment: Hi @Amadan , thank you for your response. So now I'm working with the parent as I understand the DFS index (thanks to you and thermite), so with parent, a is the parent of b, and b is the parent of g, but where do i go from there? then g is the parent of c? and c is the parent of d? etc ? Hope you can provide your assistance again. Thank you both very very much for your help :-)

Comment: Yes. [comment padding]

Comment: @Amadan , thanks again. And finally I am dealing with the Level. So the level is still kind of confusing and from what I see, it results in the exact same results as the DFI (Depth First Index)? Can you elaborate that please? Thank you again my friend!

Comment: It's just because of the specific case you have, which, as thermite mentions, is an incredibly boring case of DFS, since it ends up being linear, and so depth only increases and there is no backtracking.

Comment: @Amadan , so with the level how do I get started off? I am still a bit confused as Thermite did it with g as the starting root. Can you explain please? Thanks

Comment: Explain what? As you noted, level in your boring case is the same as index, since you're only going down. If you take for example the graph in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search#Example), the order with levels is A/1, B/2, D/3, F/3, E/4, C/2, G/3.

Comment: @Amadan , so I was correct in saying that the Index = the Level in my case? Please let me know, because that is also what I got. Just want to confirm if it is correct. thanks!!